# Remove a listener from a view in android

Tags: android, view, checkbox, listener

Is there any way to remove a Listener from a `View` in android? I have a `Checkbox` that I attached a `CheckChangedListener` to. The problem is that calling `setChecked()` on it causes my listener to fire.

If I can't just remove a listener, is there a way to prevent the listener from firing when I call `setChecked()` manually versus it being checked from a touch event?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Well, I found the answer. This doesnt appear to be documented anywhere, but I went through the code for the `View` class and if you pass null to the setClickListener methods, it will remove the listener.

```
checkbox.setOnCheckChangedListener(null);
```

This should work for any event listener.

Comment: Id be cautious about making use of undocumented features, they can change at any moment.

Comment: I wouldn't exactly call this an "undocumented feature." If a view supports a single listener of a given type and you set that one listener to null, what else would you expect to happen? :)

Comment: It's not an undocumented feature. It's just undocumented that it's safe to pass in null, which it is. The internal listener that the view uses starts as null on construction and is checked against null when determining whether to dispatch the event. Setting null just resets it to the value it is before you set a listener.

Comment: This is all good but if the view is in a list you need to also set the view to GONE in order for the listviews onListItemClick to be reenabled.

Comment: Isn't it meant to be setOnCheckedChangeListener?

Comment: OnCheckChangedListener is kinda obnoxious ;)

Answer (score 7):

Why have you got a `checkChangeListener`? If you'd use an `onClicklListener` it might just work for you?

Answer (score 2):

You could try setting the listener to one that does nothing before calling `setChecked()` and then putting the useful one back afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues with the Spinner view. My solution was to create a class member variable that I check in the `OnItemSelected` method. Before I change the contents/selection of the Spinner programmatically I set this variable to `true`. When `OnItemSelected` fires, if the variable is `true` I change it to `false` and just `return` without doing any work. The downside to this is that it makes troubleshooting difficult since this variable gets set all throughout my code.

Answer (score -3):

You just use removeListener(this). Am I missing something here?